Pygame Flood Fill "maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison"
I'm currently working on a drawing program, and attempted to implement this flood fill program.
I tried to adapt it to Pygame, however for some reason it only seems to partially work; if I leave both x lines (x+1, x-1) the program will crash. If I remove 1 x line then everything works fine. I'm not sure what may be causing this. Any help determining the issue would be appreciated, and preferable to a complete rewrite.
full_canvas = flood_fill(full_canvas,mouse_history[-1][0],mouse_history[-1][1],brush_colour,old_colour,mouse_history[-1])

def flood_fill(image,x,y,new_colour,old_colour,start_pixel):
    pixel = image.get_at((x,y))
    pixel_colour = (pixel[0],pixel[1],pixel[2])
    if x < 0 or x > image.get_width() or y < 0 or y > image.get_height() or pixel_colour == new_colour or pixel_colour != old_colour or pixel[3] < 1:
        return
    image.set_at((x,y),new_colour)
    flood_fill(image,x+1,y,new_colour,old_colour,start_pixel)
    flood_fill(image,x-1,y,new_colour,old_colour,start_pixel)
    flood_fill(image,x,y+1,new_colour,old_colour,start_pixel)
    flood_fill(image,x,y-1,new_colour,old_colour,start_pixel)

return image


there is no control there to avoid visiting already visited pixels: this will run into an infinite recursion loop.

How would you go about keeping track of visited pixels? When i try passing through the previous (x,y) coordinate as the new starting position then returning if the new (x,y) coordinates are the same, I run into the same issue or result in a NoneType image.

@jsbueno The part or pixel_colour == new_colour or pixel_colour != old_colour is meant to stop recursion.
@Oyavo Are you sure that your tuple pixel_colour = (pixel[0],pixel[1],pixel[2]) and the inputs new_colour and old_colour use the same format? If you are comparing nonsense here, you either break the recursion early or not at all.

Due to the recursion limit (1000 by default) the number of steps from the starting point is restricted. If the area to fill is larger than a diamond shape around the starting point with width and height of about 2000 pixels, your code will crash.

@aRTy all colour inputs appear to be the same when checking with isinstance and printing them out, they all return tuples containing 3 integers accurate to the colour at the position the mouse is at, colour that should be changed to, and the old colour (same as the one found at the mouse position). Not too sure how else I can avoid going over the same pixel, especially given that everything almost works.

When I was almost done rewriting your recursive approach, I noticed that you are checking x > image.get_width() or y > image.get_height(). I am not familiar with Pygame, but from what I can tell with a quick online search the image seems to be 0-indexed. This means you actually want to check x >= image.get_width() or y >= image.get_height(). A width of 100 likely means 0...99 is available and 100 is already out of bounds. You can try to change only that and see if it helps. Furthermore that check should happen before you use image.get_at((x,y)).
Consequently your first few lines probably should look like:
if x < 0 or x >= image.get_width() or y < 0 or y >= image.get_height():
    return
pixel = image.get_at((x,y))
pixel_colour = (pixel[0],pixel[1],pixel[2])
if pixel_colour == new_colour or pixel_colour != old_colour or pixel[3] < 1:
    return
image.set_at((x,y),new_colour)
...

If that does not help, you can try the following implementation instead. I changed your recursion into a depth-first approach. Pending (x,y)-points are managed in a list, already visited ones are tracked in a set (to allow fast comparison).
There is a warning in the pygame docs by the way (here) regarding image.get_at() and image.set_at():

Getting and setting pixels one at a time is generally too slow to be used in a game or realtime situation. It is better to use methods which operate on many pixels at a time like with the blit, fill and draw methods - or by using pygame.surfarray/pygame.PixelArray.

If the code is too slow, consider using pygame.PixelArray instead of get_at/set_at. I had a quick look and it seems suitable.
def flood_fill(image, x, y, new_colour, old_colour):
    visited = set()
    pending = [(x, y)]

    while pending:
        x, y = pending.pop()

        if x < 0 or x >= image.get_width() or y < 0 or y >= image.get_height():  # out of bounds
            continue

        pixel = image.get_at((x, y))
        pixel_colour = (pixel[0], pixel[1], pixel[2])

        if pixel_colour == new_colour or pixel_colour != old_colour or pixel[3] < 1:
            continue

        image.set_at((x, y), new_colour)

        for point in ((x + 1, y), (x - 1, y), (x, y + 1), (x, y - 1)):
            if point not in visited:
                pending.append(point)
                visited.add(point)


Wow, works perfectly. Thank you! I'll have to look more into set() and continue because I'm honestly not too familiar with it. Thanks for the help.

@Oyavo Sets are one of the basic Python datatypes. They are about element membership. Elements in a set have no particular order. Sets can not be accessed via index for that reason. Essentially the only information they track is "element is in the set" (or not in). Consequently they also eliminate duplicates. A set is very useful here because visited only needs to track points in a yes/no fashion. Checking membership in a set is very fast, because they are built for exactly this check. The "continue" just means "skip the rest of the current loop and continue with the next element".
